# Deleting the nth character of a string in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, sed, linux-mint

Given is the following text-file:

```
1 star wars
4 munich
5 casino royale
7 the fast and the furious
52 a fish called wanda
```

Each line starts with a number, this number presents the nth character that I want to delete in the sentence next to the word.
The output should be:

```
tar wars
munch
casio royale
the fat and furious
a fish called wanda
```

I wanted to do something like this:

```
cat numberFile.txt | sed "s/^\([0-9]\) \(.*\)$/echo \2 | sed 's/\w//\1/'/g"
```

But this obviously doesn't work. So if anybody knows how.

Comment: If this is a homework question you should check the cheating policy of your school.

Comment: These are optional exercises, and our professors don't have the time to put the answers online, so that's why we asked it on here. There is no such thing as homework for us